# Disable DSUSP in Python

Tags: python, macos, tty, fcntl, termios

An OSX user [submitted a bug](https://github.com/bpython/bpython/issues/507) that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> causes a python terminal application [to be suspended](http://bugs.python.org/issue16768), via [dsusp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Characters.html) causing SIGTSTP to be sent when the Python program tried to read on stdin. The code below to solves the problem: ([context](https://github.com/thomasballinger/curtsies/compare/fix-ctrl-y...disable-ctrl-y))

```
import sys
import termios
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    attrs = termios.tcgetattr(0)
    VDSUSP = termios.VSUSP + 1
    attrs[-1][VDSUSP] = 0
    termios.tcsetattr(0, termios.TCSANOW, attrs)
```

- How can this feature (dsusp) be detected? Is there a heuristic I could use based on `os.uname()` or similar?
- `termios.VDSUSP` doesn't exist, even on systems that have it. Is there a reason it's missing?
- How widespread is this behavior of turning it off? Programs that use readline seem to ignore <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> on OSX, so it's at least reasonably common. I added `stty dsusp undef` to my .bashrc long ago so haven't noticed it.

To see this suspend behavior, run `cat` and enter <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd> on OSX or something else with this feature.

```
$ cat
^Y

[1]+ Stopped             cat
$ fg
cat
cat: stdin: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unable to check the actual behaviour for this as I do not have any computers with an operating system that would have the `DSUSP` behaviour. 
However while investigating the issue, I came across [issue 7695 in Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue7695). It seems that the `VDSUSP` is available in `termios` only from 3.4 onwards.

---

[Glibc documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Characters.html), that says

> Macro: int `VDSUSP`
>
> This is the subscript for the `DSUSP` character in the special control character array. `termios.c_cc[VDSUSP]` holds the character itself.
>
> The `DSUSP` (suspend) character is recognized only if the implementation supports job control (see Job Control). It sends a `SIGTSTP` signal, like the `SUSP` character, but not right away—only when the program tries to read it as input. Not all systems with job control support DSUSP; **only BSD-compatible systems (including GNU/Hurd systems)**.

---

Thus I'd propose that you'd check the existence of `VDSUSP` in `termios` - it *will* be there from 3.4 onwards; and otherwise fall back to

```
if any(i in sys.platform for i in ['bsd', 'darwin']):
```

Which should match BSD and your OS X; the Hurd is a big question mark since I couldn't find out whether your fix would be correct at all there or not (I guess it would work similarly on all BSD versions).

Even easier would be to just do:

```
import subprocess
import time
from distutils.spawn import find_executable

def exec_cmd(*args):
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, _ = p.communicate()
    return stdout

if find_executable('stty'):
    modesave = exec_cmd('stty', '-g').strip()
    exec_cmd('stty', 'dsusp', 'undef')
    print("disabled ctrl-y")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("enabled ctrl-y")
    exec_cmd('stty', modesave)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("exiting")
```

At least this does not blow up my Linux, and the `stty` command itself and `-g` etc are POSIX standards.